# c++11 decltype(e) is the type of the entity named by e

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, decltype

I am not asking `decltype((x))`, I know how it works.

According to the draft N4687, § 10.1.7.2

```
    4 For an expression e, the type denoted by decltype(e) is defined as follows:
        ...
(4.2)   — otherwise, if e is an unparenthesized id-expression or an unparenthesized class
          member access (8.2.5), decltype(e) is the type of the entity named by e. If
          there is no such entity, or if e names a set of overloaded functions, the
          program is ill-formed;
        ...
```

And example

```
struct A { double x; };
const A* a = new A();
decltype(a->x) x3; // type is double
```

My question is,
`a->x` is `const double`, but why does x3 is `double`? where does the `const` go?
BTW, what is `decltype(e) is the type of the entity named by e` meaning exactly?

Comment: a->x is const double? you just declared it as double x not const double

Comment: I know `x` is declared as double. But `a->x` is `e`, and `e` is `const double`, so the `x` is `const double`, isn't it?

Comment: File a bug report

Comment: I don't think the members of a `const` object are literally `const` themselves unless declared `const` in the class definition. It's just forbidden to modify them.

Comment: @user2357112 - They are const. The qualifier applies recursively to members of aggregates. This case is simply specified to behave otherwise (though not to clearly).

Comment: @StoryTeller I think there's a communication gap here.  The _expression_ `a->x` is of type `const double`.  But the _entity named by_ the expression, aka the member, is of type `double`.

Comment: @HWalters - Your'e a little late to the party. That has been established. The whole confusion is due to "entity" being a poorly defined term.

Comment: I'm not "late to the party"; I was reading this in real time.  And yes, this has been established.  I'm _only_ addressing your specific comment to user2357112; in particular, -> "They are const" <-.  That's still wrong; the member specifically in this case is still, exactly as he just said, type `double`.  (And I'm just commenting for your benefit; you mentioned this was confusing ("not to clearly"), I'm just hoping to clarify).

Comment: @HWalters - Your altruism on my behalf is duly noted. But my comment was in relation to the standard using unclear wording, I assure you I stopped being confused long before you chose to explain it to me.

Comment: The discussion of the expression type is a bit misleading. ``a->x`` is an lvalue expression of type ``const double``. This means ``decltype((a->x))`` is ``const double&`` (a reference is added for lvalue expressions).

Comment: @ArneVogel () has special rule. (4.4) — otherwise, if e is an lvalue, decltype(e) is T&, where T is the type of e; But (4.2) says "decltype(e) is the type of the entity named by e". They are different.

Comment: @Caesar: Sure, my point is that if ``a->x`` did *not* refer to an entity, then ``decltype(a->x)`` should be ``const double&``.

Answer (score 6):

The standard seems ambiguous im this area.

> An *entity* is a value, object, reference, function, enumerator, type, class member, bit-field, template, template specialization, namespace, or parameter pack.

The expression `a->x` can be said to name a *member* `x` of `struct A`, which has type `double`. The same expression can also be said to name an *object* which has type `const double`. Both of these things are entities. The normative text doesn't make it absolutely clear that the intended interpretation is the first one, it can only be inferred from the example.

Comment: Where does the entity definition appear? Oh, and +1 either way.

Comment: It seems like entity can be everything.

Comment: @StoryTeller `[basic]/3` (you can find a pointer in the index).

Comment: It has been said that the only reason CWG introduced "entity" is because "thingy" was considered inappropriate for an ISO standard.

Comment: @T.C. They have also removed the atomic decay footnote. Never forgive, never forget.

Comment: There's a subtle distinction here. The *type* of a member subobject isn't affected by the cv-qualification of its complete object. It's hard to prove a negative, of course, but it can be inferred from the definition of "const object" as "an object of type `const T` or a non-mutable subobject of such an object" in [\[basic.type.qualifier\]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.type.qualifier#1.1) (and likewise for `volatile`). The second part of the definition would have been completely superfluous if cv-qualification on the complete object affected the type of its subobjects.

Comment: This rarely matters, because the just mentioned definition of "const object" includes such subobjects, and the specification of class member access likewise propagates cv-qualification, but here it does.

Comment: @T.C. It can also be inferred from [expr.ref]¶4.2 which explains how the cv-qual of the object and the cv-qual of the member combine to form the cv-qual of the member access expression. If the type of a member subobject were affected by the cv-qual of its complete object, then this part of ¶4.2 would be redundant.

Answer (score 4):

> N4687 [dcl.type.simple] ¶4.2 ...if `e` is an unparenthesized *id-expression* or an unparenthesized class member access, `decltype(e)` is the type of the entity named by `e`.

A class member access is either `.` or `->`, according to [expr.ref].

> [basic] ¶3 An *entity* is a value, object, reference, function, enumerator, type, class member, bit-field, template, template specialization, namespace, or parameter pack.
>
> ¶4 A *name* is a use of an *identifier*, *operator-function-id*, *literal-operator-id*, *conversionfunction-id*, or *template-id* that denotes an entity or label.
>
> ¶5 Every name that denotes an entity is introduced by a *declaration*.

There is an ambiguity here: `a->x` is both a class member and an object (a member subobject). The important thing to note is that `decltype(e)` is the type of the entity **named by** `e`. The only kinds of entities that can be **named** are those that are introduced by declarations (¶5). A member subobject does not have a name in this sense, as it is not declared. That leaves the only other alternative that `decltype(x->a)` must be the type of the class member (not the object member).

Answer (score 1):

The "entity" named by a class member access expression is that class member, in this case, `A::x`.

The type of `A::x` is `double`.

Comment: You might want to add that this is the same as `A::x` *because* the very same paragraph mentions and applies to an id-expression.

Comment: Could you give me help? Where do you find the definition of `entity named`?

Comment: @Caesar - It's poor wording by the standard. "id-expression" (as mentioned in the paragraph) is something like `A::x`. Surely you agree that should resolve to `double`. Well, that bullet you quoted pretty much says `A::x` and `a->x` resolve to the same.